# how to stop Firestore transaction from retrying

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I stop a firestore transaction from retrying after it has been run for the first time . I have a function which I want to run once so that if there is a network problem it does not retry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this logic depending on your needs

```
bool runFirst = true;

if (runFirst) {
  runFirst = false;
  // this block runs just once
} else {
  // this blocks runs for later calls
}
```